# error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to display a `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionViewCell`, the app crashes and I'm getting the following error:

> 2018-07-21 09:14:10.498749+0300 Shippers[18104:819840] *** Assertion failure in -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1452.23/Foundation/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISEngine.m:1888
>   error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

This `RankingVC` is being added as a ChildViewController. Not sure where the problem is, but if I comment out all the `UICollectionView` stuff in the file, the app doesn't crash, so there must be something wrong with that.

```
class RankingVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupCollectionViewDelegates()
    registerCells()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
}
}

extension RankingVC  : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func setupCollectionViewDelegates() {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier.rankingCVCell, for: indexPath) as! RankingCVCell
        return cell 
    }

    func registerCells() {
        RegisterCVCells.registerCell(withNibName: CellIdentifier.rankingCVCell, forCollectionView: collectionView)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method, should you be casting the dequeued cell to your custom cell class?

Comment: @Chris you are right, I forgot to do that and I thought that would solve the problem, but even with the casting, I still get the same error

Comment: @Balaji doesnt change anything, it still crashes with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting programmatically the height of the `UICollectionViewCell` to be higher than the cell itself. Making sure that the minimum height of each cell is at least equal to the shortest (in terms of height) cell solve this issue.